# Spring xml config to java config converter

Tags: java, xml, spring

Is there a tool, which can convert Spring xml configs to java configs? I have a lot of large xml configs and don't want to convert in manually.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but it's something you could write. I can see Spring config moving exclusively to it's Java form soon, so it might not be needed in the future.

Check this book out, the third chapter has some examples on how to do this.

http://www.gocit.vn/files/Spring.in.Action.3rd.Edition-www.gocit.vn.pdf